# how to user Json Value in anchor tag data attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have an anchor tag which is used to store 'Search-type' in its data-search_type attribute.

on anchor tag click this value is used by $.post ajax method to search for data based on the numbers,
But if you look properly the because of ""(double quotes) in json the data-search_criteria stores "[" as value and ignores the rest of the data.

so my question is what to do to make this data available to $.post method?

```
<a class="showresult" data-search_type = "Search by Cost" data-search_criteria="["0","1"]" href="#">Open Search</a>
```

Comment: How are you putting the data into the attribute in the 1st place - javascript? php?

Comment: i am getting the data from the database and storing it through php array

Comment: what like `data-search_criteria="<?php echo $json;?>" href=...`? then simply change to `data-search_criteria='<?php echo $json;?>' href=...` **note single quotes** as per answer by @KJPrice

Comment: oh it was so simple! thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the containing double quotes " with single quotes '

```
<a class="showresult" data-search_type = "Search by Cost" data-search_criteria='["0","1"]' href="#">Open Search</a>
```

Comment: how to do that dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How are you creating the html? However you create the html, that is how you would change it dynamically. If it is static html, then just change the source for the static html.

Comment: data in the data-search_criteria comes from database and the values are in json

Comment: Check out comment from user574632 above. You just change the double quote to a single quote.

Comment: solution was so simple and i was thinking of removing double quotes in  json data, My stupidity!

Comment: Lol. No worries. I think we've all been there before. I'm glad you were able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `&quot;` to represent a `"` character in an attribute value delimited by `"` characters.